# ESLint on VSCode doesn't format all languages, including JSON, with Allman style

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, formatting, eslint

I hate [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) because they have taken off my freedom to use my favourite brace style.

I use [CSSComb](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-csscomb), [PHP CS Fixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fterrag.vscode-php-cs-fixer) and [SCSS Allman Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GrantBartlett.scss-allman-formatter). They support Allman style. VSCode comes with native JavaScript and TypeScript brace style settings:

```json
{
 "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
 "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
 "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
 "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
}
```

The problem is that these settings are only for few languages. I want to format all database, data format, markup and programming languages, including JSON, except Python, with Allman style.

I have seen they have recommended ESLint to replace Prettier and the discontinued JS Beautifier.

I trained myself with ESLint documentation articles [Getting started](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/getting-started) and [Configuring ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/).

1. I created `package.json` and I saved ESLint development dependencies on the project. Here is `project/package.json`:

   ```json
   {
     "editor.codeActionsOnSave": 
     {
       "source.fixAll.eslint": true
     },
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    "eslint.validate": 
    [
      "css",
      "javascript",
      "json",
      "jsonc",
      "markdown",
      "scss",
      "typescript"
    ],
   }
   ```
2. I created `.eslintrc` file in YAML format on project folder. Here is `project/.eslintrc.yml`:

   ```yaml
   env:
     browser: true
     es2021: true
     node: true
   overrides: []
   parserOptions:
     ecmaVersion: latest
   rules:
     brace-style:
       - error
       - allman
   ```
3. And I configured `project/.vscode/settings.json`:

   ```json
   {
     "editor.codeActionsOnSave": 
     {
       "source.fixAll.eslint": true
     },
     "eslint.format.enable": true,
     "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
     "eslint.validate": 
     [
       "css",
       "javascript",
       "json",
       "jsonc",
       "markdown",
       "scss",
       "typescript"
     ],
   }
   ```

I also have run ESLint. I have open Command Palette and chose Format Document. But it didn't give effect. It didn't format.

I also have tested, creating `eslintrc.json` and it almost worked, but it didn't format JSON files with Allman styles.

I really miss Atom, that allowed me to use Allman style for almost all languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [eslint-plugin-json](https://github.com/azeemba/eslint-plugin-json/issues/8#issuecomment-604294953) does not support auto fixing by now. Thankfully, another completely separate dependency [eslint-plugin-json-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-json-format) does.

Firstly, make sure you have `eslint` installed either global or local.  Secondly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > Open UI Settings, and search for `eslint.probe` and add `json` if it's not added. Then, issue either:

- `npm install eslint-plugin-json-format --save-dev`
- `yarn add -D eslint-plugin-json-format`

Next, include this in your `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    "json-format"
  ]
}
```

Now craft a JSON with some comments or disalligned and run:

```
eslint --fix yourfile.json
```

To see it in action.

Comment: It has formatted the JSON and JSONC files, but sadly, it hasn't enforced Allman style on them (`brace-style`).

Comment: @GustavoReis there's a hacky solution to it. Open `node_modules > eslint-plugin-json-format > lib > index.js` and modify line 106 to:   

`const formatted = formatJSON(parsed).replaceAll(/([ \t]*)(".*":)\s*([\{\[])/gm, '$1$2\n$1$3')`

Comment: It worked for any JSON files, but does not work for `package.json` and JSONC files like `settings.json`.

Comment: It is the expected behavior. Please look at the dependency documentation I've linked to change it.

Comment: What is the similar regular expression to your regular expression for `awk` or `sed`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set json file default formatter, add this to your vscode settings.json, it will make vscode use your default editor formatter for json file, such as ESLint.

```json
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
  }
```